# php 5.x 7.x, ssl pdo error: Peer certificate CN=`someName' did not match expected CN='someIP'

Tags: mysql, ssl, pdo, php-7, php-5.6

We have a server with mysql on port 3306. We have sertifications and key and we try to connect to this server. But we see such problem:

> Peer certificate CN='SomeName' did not match expected CN='someIP'

I've read a lot of articles and can't find answer for PDO PHP. The most interesting is that the SQLYog could connect with all settings.

I've read that I verify_peer_names can be disabled (I hope I understand what is peer_names...), but only if we use openssl_{functions} or mysqli, not PDO. Both options are not appropriate for me. I need PDO.

What I tried to do:

- switch between versions of php. It helped me, but I need 5.6 or higher. For php 7.0 the same error.
- find another versions of openssl and pdo; fast I understood that its a bad idea :)
- find some settings in php.ini, but no settings for my problem, only for creating ssl.

My code for connection:

```
$dbInfo = array
(
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=123.45.67.890;dbname=someDB;port=3306',
'user' => 'user',
'pass' => 'userpassword'
);

$con = new PDO
    (
    $dbInfo['dsn'], $dbInfo['user'], $dbInfo['pass'], 
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CIPHER => 'AES256-SHA',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA     => 'SSLCert/ca-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    => 'SSLCert/client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT   => 'SSLCert/client-cert.pem',
    )
    );

echo 'Connection OK!';
```

Comment: It's a known issue, see: [php bug #71003](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71003)

Comment: Thanks man!
But I still don't understand what I have to do with ssl connection. I read that they fix it in some patch, they dig openssl lib, but first I'm not a good to dig inside a lib, second - it's not a good idea to fix lib by myself. Maybe I'm carelles and didn't find the answer... If you worked and solved this problem for yourself - can you hint me somehow what to do?

Answer (score 3):

We got it working for our internal self-signed certs by not using IP addresses but machine(+domain) names as the CN and connection settings.

So, put `'dbServer1.company.local'` as the CN for the server certificate and use the same `'dbServer1.company.local'` address as the host part of the DSN for the PDO connection. If you like, you can just use `'dbServer1'` but make sure you use it in both places.

This will get you going:

```
$pdo_options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'path/to/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'path/to/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => 'path/to/ca.pem'
);

PDO::__construct('mysql:host=dbServer1.company.local;dbname=someDB','someUser', 'somePass', $pdo_options);
```

We manage our own DNS so resolving `dbServer1.company.local` is not an issue but if your webserver cannot resolve it you or you don't/can't manage the DNS entry, then hack in something like the following to your `etc/hosts` file:

```
10.5.5.20 dbServer1.company.local
```

or

```
10.5.5.20 dbServer1
```

Comment: I can't say that you are right or you wrong for sure, because I don't keep this project for half an year. But I think you say right things.

Comment: I wrote this answer for anybody else who visits the page. I guessed you would have moved on by now.

Comment: Sure moved on! :) I just write that I can't check what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to *consider* is setting

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
```

**Not a good option for top security**, but in some cases it could be OK and possibly simpler than the DNS/CA match suggested separately.