# PHP mysqli cannot recognize SSL certificates to remote database

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I want to connect with remote mysql database via mysqli function. Connection also requires SSL certificates in order to get access there. So my code looks like this:

```
$db = array(
            "host" => "host",
            "user" => "user",
            "password" => "password",
            "dbName" => "dbName"
        );

        ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
        ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
        error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);

        $connection = mysqli_init();
        mysqli_options ($connection, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

        $connection->ssl_set('/usr/local/certs/client-key.pem',
 '/usr/local/certs/client-cert.pem', '/usr/local/certs/server-ca.pem', NULL, NULL);
        $link = mysqli_real_connect ($connection, $db['host'],
 $db['user'], $db['password'], $db['dbName'], 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

 if (!$link)
        {
            die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): '
 . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $response = $connection->query('SHOW TABLES;');
            $this->output->writeln($response);
            $connection->close();
        }
```

And then I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): Peer certificate CN=`[project 
name]' did not match expected CN=`[IP address]`
```

I'm struggling with this error for few days. I'm also 100% sure that my certificates and paths are correct. How can I fix it and establish connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php 5.x 7.x, ssl pdo error: Peer certificate CN=\`someName' did not match expected CN='someIP'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719607/php-5-x-7-x-ssl-pdo-error-peer-certificate-cn-somename-did-not-match-expecte)

Comment: unfortunately it's not the same issue. Author of that topic used PDO not mysqli so I still don't know what I should fix in my code

Comment: Read more carefully! Their solution is completely unrelated of mysqli / PDO and has to do with how the CN is set on the cert.

Comment: So I should write something like "10.5.5.20 dbServer1.company.local" on my /etc/host file and then use dbServer1.company.local instead of regular IP address on my $db array in php file? Im sorry maybe it's  bit silly question but I'm a newbie in PHP/mysql connections

Comment: In a certificate under "Issued To", you have "Common Name (CN)". There you can have one or more FQDNs or IP addresses. When you load the website with a domain name or IP that is not part of the CN, the certificate will be invalid for that session.

Comment: where I can find that "Issued To" part? I mean in those three files (client-cert, key-cert server-ca) I've got just a bunch of random chars without this option

Comment: You need to learn about certificates. You cannot change anything in an existing certificate. You submit a signing request to an official Certificate Authority. They verify your details and cryptographically sign the certificate. You must submit all required CNs in your signing request.

Comment: So basically I cannot connect with that DB without new fixed certificates? Then why I can establish connection with mysql via terminal using those certificates? I just type something like: mysql -u .... /--ssl-ca=server-ca.pem ect and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to set MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT to **false** before it all worked.

Try the following instead:

```
mysqli_options ($connection, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, false);
```

Hope it works and also for the benefit of later readers.

Comment: Wouldn't this make the connection vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack?